# Why is Akka logging async?

Tags: scala, logging, akka

Akka logging is async so that it will be non-blocking. But I find that the order of the logging statements are not guaranteed as they are async. What good is logging if the order of log statements are not meaningful?

Comment: "the order of the logging statements are not guaranteed as they are async" - sure they are ordered if they come from the _same actor_?

Comment: Log messages from the same actor are ordered.  Given that Akka is async top-to-bottom there's really no concept of global order anyways.